# Embedding SVGs and keeping links

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG located here: https://bri-roes-web-test.surge.sh/test.svg

When you load the full SVG you can see there are links and the links work.

I need to load the SVG into a page, but I only have access to the CSS of the page. I can use the `::after` property to get it to show on the page:

https://codepen.io/thindery/pen/QXVgqE

However, links don't work anymore.

Does anyone have a suggestion on another way I can load the SVG and still have the links working?

Comment: What about Javascript? Do you have access to it or can add a script to the page?

Comment: Unfortunately no access to use JS. I can only edit a CSS file.

Comment: You're not going to find this is possible then.